# How to use lock to manage access to different type of resources?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, thread-safety, locking

I need to synchronize execution of piece of code for several different types of resources.

For a given resource type, only one thread should be able to execute piece of code at a time. Same piece of code can be executed by multiple threads as long as all threads are working on different types of resources.

Let me know if following approach is right or wrong.

Function GetResourceTypeLockObject returns different lock objects based on given type in parameter. Each object is previously created readonly object.

```
GetResourceTypeLockObject(TypeEnum type)
{
  
 if type == 1 
   return type1LockObject;

 else if type == 2
   return type2LockObject;

 else if type == 3
   return type3LockObject;
}


WorkOnResource(TypeEnum type)
{
 var lockObject = GetResourceTypeLockObject(type);

lock(lockObject)
{
 // Manipulate resource of given type

}

}
```

Comment: As pseudo-code it looks correct.

Comment: ...except that `WorkOnResource(...)` ought to guarantee that it _unlocks_ the same lock object before it returns or throws an exception.